# How to use TextInputLayout with Theme.material?

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm trying to use TextInputLayout with Theme.material and the code look like....

activity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:drawableLeft="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    tools:context="com.realmilk.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Account Login"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_supervisor_account_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableTint="#FF4081"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:hint="User Name"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableTint="#FF4081"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="numberPassword" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Forgot Password?" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="22dp"
                android:background="#d67601"
                android:text="Sign in"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/user_profile_image_background"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The MainActivity look like this..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

When i try to execute this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.                                                                 
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
           at com.realmilk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

This was at console I observed.

Can anyone help me to find where I have mistaken.

Comment: post your `style.xml` please

Comment: What's the problem in using `Theme.AppCompat` theme ?

Comment: <resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: @utkarshdubey I would like to use material design.

Comment: should i need to create another styles.xml for Material design?

Comment: check my answer @KiranRaju

Comment: You just need to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Everything else is perfect not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

change following files

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        </style>
</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1a237e</color>
    <color name="transparent">@android:color/transparent</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#313131</color>

</resources>
```

> you can change colors as per your need.

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    //your activities

</application>
```

hope this helps...

Comment: I'm unable to save the file styles.xml with <style> tag.. If i put <resource> tag instead of that it is not accepting in manifest xml as app name.

Comment: I'm looking for standard Material Setup.

Comment: you can check this [**material tutorial**](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)

Answer (score 0):

TextInputLayout is part of the `support` library (as you see it's part of the design library). All support component from support libraries are written to be complementary with other support components like Themes. In this case you need to use `Theme.AppCompat`. But don't worry, all compat ui elements are built to support older Android versions but if you'll use app compat theme it'll automatically use Material theme implementation to generate UI in your app.

To sum up: you must you `Theme.AppCompat` but it equals Material Theme in the Android OS >= 5.0

Just use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

instead of standard Material.